# sed doesn't catch all sets of doubles

Tags: shell, sed

I've writted a `sed` script to replace all `^^` with `NULL`. It seems though that `sed` is only catching a pair, but not including the second in that pair as it continues to search.

```
echo "^^^^" | sed 's/\^\^/\^NULL\^/g'
```

produces

```
^NULL^^NULL^
```

when it should produce

```
^NULL^NULL^NULL^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a loop to apply your command again to modified pattern space:

```
echo "^^^^" | sed ':a;s/\^\^/\^NULL\^/;t a;'
```

To edit a file in place on OSX, try the `-i` flag and multiline command:

```
sed -i '' ':a
s/\^\^/\^NULL\^/
t a' file
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i ':a;s/\^\^/\^NULL\^/;t a;' file
```

or simply redirect the command to a temporary file before renaming it:

```
sed ':a;s/\^\^/\^NULL\^/;t a;' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: your answer doesn't seem to work — it returns the original string

Comment: Seems to work on the example, but not when passed a file

Comment: Seems to depend on which version of sed.  `gsed` (GNU sed) seems to work, but stock `sed` (on my mac) doesn't edit the stream.

Comment: @SLePort what is the purpose of the empty-string `''` as the backup file extension to `sed -i''`? You could just omit the empty string and it would be equivalent?

Comment: To edit in place with GNU sed: just `sed -i`, on OSX:  `sed -i ''`.

Comment: Mac stuff... I like the solution.

Comment: Interesting, I'm still not seeing this work when passed a file `sed -i '' ':a;s/\^\^/\^NULL\^/;ta;' NUT_DATA.txt`

Comment: My original solution does edit the file, albeit incorrectly. `sed -i '' 's/\^\^/\^NULL\^/g' NUT_DATA.txt`

Comment: How are you populating `NUT_DATA.txt` ? Test with `echo '^^^^' > NUT_DATA.txt`. Works fine on Linux (can't test Mac here...) If **NUT** (*Network UPS Tools*) is populating it, check that there are no embedded control chars with, e.g. `hexdump -C NUT_DATA.txt`

Comment: It's a text file d/l from the USDA nutritional db containing rows like `01001^203^0.85^16^0.074^1^NULL^NULL^NULL^^^^^^^NULL^11/1976^`

Comment: Does in contain an embedded *Byte Order Mark* for UTF-8 `(0xEF 0xBB 0xBF)` at the beginning? (it may be a char-set issue -- who knows what the gov't is using...) I would `hexdump` and confirm.

Comment: It comes as ASCII, encoded in `LATIN-1`, but I've `recode`d it to `utf8`

Comment: Not sure the `t` command works on BSD sed. Maybe a Mac sed user could confirm.

Comment: Labels in standard sed are quirky: they have to be terminated by newline; `;` does not work. Yah, weird.

Comment: `t` seems to work on BSD sed. Try to add a space: `t a`.

Comment: No go on the space.

Comment: I tried with your file. It perfectly worked with GNU sed.

Comment: Well that's annoying. Thanks for the work guys. Really appreciate it.

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out, the GNU sed solution works on mac as long as you write it out to a new file. Apparently the issue is editing in place.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [SLePort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396664/2002514) solution, but since it is not working for you, you can try with (tested on Linux, not Mac):

```
echo "^^^^" | sed 's/\^\^/\^NULL\^/g; s//\^NULL\^/g'
```

It is doing the same as the former solution, but explicitly, not looping with tags.

You can omit the pattern in the second command and sed will use the previous pattern.

Comment: The issue was apparently with editing the file in place. That said, your solution is a nice alternative.